# Defining a 'way' to contain fixed length data c#

Tags: c#, fixed-length-record

[image]

I have the data of the Element Description column in my database.
How do I write them to a text file while respecting the 'start position' column ?

I tried using an array with a specific length but cannot figure out how to get the values on the text files.

Help ?

Comment: Please give us more information. Example of text file and DB kind will be helpful for the answer

Comment: Can you define "respecting the start position column"? In what way? The line number? The horizontal position separated by a delimeter? How?

Comment: text file (.txt) and I am using the SSMS 2012.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I meant that the reporting Record Identifier should be in first position as its length is 1 (1AN = length 1 and is alphanumeric, in Elemnt Attribute column) the next,i mean, System Provider Reporting Period Ending Date will be statring at the second position and so on.

Comment: Do you mean storing in a text file such that, when reading it, there is no doubt about the original structure? A CSV file should deliver an easy and accurate solution for your problem. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudo solved my case guys

Thanks to Saritha.S.R.

```
string a=string.Empty;
    StreamWriter yourStream = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            yourStream = File.CreateText("D:\\test1.txt"); // creating file
            a = String.Format("|{0,1}|{1,2}|{2,7}|......", "A", "B", "",......); //formatting text based on poeition
            yourStream.Write(a+"\r\n");                        
            yourStream.Close();
        }
```